# Drupal Help... How to Edit Specific Page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

Going crazy trying to find where in the drupal system I can edit this page:

http://www.luxewinecellars.com/products/wine-cooling-units-0

I've have full admin access to drupal but can't edit this page form the web interface and can't find anywhere in the backend/drop down admin system to be able to access to edit this page.

Adding to the confusion is when I use the admin top bar I get to a completely different version of this page I want to edit, I get to it from:

Store Administration --> Products --> Product Categories 
(then I click the "Wine Cooling Units" link and I get the following page)

http://www.luxewinecellars.com/products/wine-cooling-units

Can someone help me find/understand how to edit this page: http://www.luxewinecellars.com/products/wine-cooling-units-0

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a Catalog page, you can do it if you create a file named **uc_catalog_browse.tpl.php**

You have the catalog id in the argument 1 of the page (in the wine cooling units page, the catalog id is 26: http://www.luxewinecellars.com/catalog/26)

Then, you can load the entire catalog using this code:

```
$tid = arg(1);
if($tid){
    $catalog = uc_catalog_get_page((int)$tid); //Catalog
    drupal_set_title(check_plain($catalog->name));  //Title of the page
    drupal_set_breadcrumb(uc_catalog_set_breadcrumb($catalog->tid));   //Breadcrums

    //Do something
}
```

I hope its useful.

Regards.